# How do I initialize a variable on an object class creation, to the return of a parent function?

Tags: python, oop

I am creating a Lottery simulator, and am trying to initialize a Child class (called Checker) with a variable called win_ticket.  To obtain this winning ticket, I attempt to call a method which itself belongs to a Root class of Checker.

On the creation of Checker() object: like
c = Checker(),
it appears to successfully initialize **c.win_ticket** and assign it a **winning_ticket**, but then it immediately "forgets" it.  I have gone step by step through debugging and there is a moment where self.win_ticket does have the correct assignment, but then it forgets it!

It is then of Nonetype, but I can then invoke, **c.draw_lottery()** myself and only then does it successfully "remember" the variable **c.win_ticket**.

Could someone explain or point to the idea of why an object on creation appears to assign itself a variable on an **init**() and then forgets it?  Thank you in advance.

```
class Checker(Ticket):
    """
    Will check purchased tickets against the winning ticket drawn from root Class MegaMillion
    TODO I can't seem to have self.winticket automatically draw and initialize!
    """
    def __init__(self, cost=2) -> None:
        super(Checker, self).__init__(cost)
        # list of tuples (3,1), (0,1) to match with prize_dict
        self.ticket_match_list = []
        self.winnings = 0
        self.win_ticket = self.draw_lottery()
```

It is trying to obtain the method from its Parent(or is it called grandparent?) class

```
class MegaMillions():
    """"""

    def __init__(self,  cost=2) -> None:
        self.win_ticket = None
        self.cost = cost

    def draw_numbers(self, times=1):
        """Return a list of numbers [(a, b, c, d, e), f ] """

        number_list = []
        for i in range(times):
            numbers = (sorted(random.sample(list(range(1, 71)), k=5))
                       ), (random.randint(1, 25))
            number_list.append(numbers)
        return number_list

    def draw_lottery(self) -> list:
        """Draws and sets the lottery winning ticket"""

        self.win_ticket = self.draw_numbers()
        print(f"\n Tonight's winning ticket is ...: {self.win_ticket}")
        logger.info(f"win_ticket is: {self.win_ticket}")

class Ticket(MegaMillions):
    """
    Models purchasing tickets.  
    It can buy_tickets()  
    Can ask_number_tickets requested and buy them.
    """

    def __init__(self, cost=2) -> None:
        super().__init__(cost)
        self.ticket_list = None
        self.ticket_req = None
        self.total_tickets_purchased = 0

...extra code...

class Checker(Ticket):
    """
    Will check purchased tickets against the winning ticket drawn 
   from root Class MegaMillion
   TODO initialize self.net
    TODO I can't seem to have self.win_ticket automatically draw and initialize!
    """

    def __init__(self, cost=2) -> None:
        super(Checker, self).__init__(cost)
        # list of tuples (3,1), (0,1) to match with prize_dict
        self.ticket_match_list = []
        self.winnings = 0
        self.win_ticket = self.draw_lottery()
```

Comment: do you mean `logger.info` or `logging.info`? In case, could you fix the import**s**?

Comment: `self.win_ticket` from `Checker` is called **twice**, once with `super().__init__`, hence it is first `None` then it's initialized to a `list` object. A _grampa-style_ inheritance could not be the right solution here, maybe with composition?

Comment: ah, I forgot to delete that logger out, I tried to clean up the code a bit to make it easier to read through but must have missed that.  

I am not familiar with composition, I will read up on it now to better understand why my grandpa style isn't the best.  Thank you for the lead!